# how to handle php echo'ed message in ajax.

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am creating an AJAX+PHP submit form, for example purposes. For this, I will need Ajax, PHP and index.html file to write into the inputs. The problem is that, when I submit I have no way of redirecting a page, so I created this hack. (since page redirect get permission from the PHP script first) otherwise show error.

#### AJAX

```
function submit_form(){
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 

     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {

            if(xmlhttp.responseText.trim() == 'success'){
                location.href = '/success';
            }           
       // 
       var e = doc.querySelector('.form-error').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

        }
}
```

And this is my PHP.

```
<?php 
   echo "/success";
if($_GET){

}else{
 echo "error, no value found"; 
}
```

as you can see, this allows me to redirect the page, as the javascript will read the `"/success"` and redirect the document, but one problem with this is that, I don't like using echo, because the page actually shows "success" before redirect. I don't want it to show anything to the page.

Comment: your code never redirect the page on js side. your response from php is `/success` and when `xmlhttp.responseText.trim()` that will never cut the slash.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `echo` statement to `return json_encode()`, then in your JS code, you can parse it using `JSON.parse()`;

Comment: Thanks. But, what difference does sending data as json do in this context? Is that how all PHP, Ajax data is transfered?

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP removes the slash of this line: `echo "/success";`

And in your java script code, add a else sentence before print error:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
        if(xmlhttp.responseText.trim() == 'success') {
            location.href = '/success';
        }
        else {
            var e = doc.querySelector('.form-error').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
}
```